# How to force linking of a symbol from a particular library?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld, linker-scripts

When linking an executable on Linux i get an 'undefined reference' error like this:

```
undefined reference to `symbol@SOMELIB_1.0'
```

I do not have a control of 'SOMELIB', but ***I do have*** the symbol `symbol` in one of my own shared libraries. I'm absolutely sure that the **symbol@SOMELIB_1.0** is the same (provides exactly the same functionality) that the symbol in my library, actually even the source code is almost the same.

How to force/alias the `symbol@SOMELIB_1.0` to be linked from my library, not from `SOMELIB_1.0` ?
I was thinking about some kind of symbol versioning tricks in linker script, but I could not find any solution or even clues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After loooong fight (and search) I found a solution [here](http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=33).
To summarize: I needed two symbols. In my source code I put something like this:

```
__asm__(".symver symbol1, symbol1@SOMELIB_1.0");
void symbol1(void)
{
.....
}

__asm__(".symver symbol2, symbol2@SOMELIB_1.0");
void symbol2(void)
{
.....
}
```

Then I needed a liker script *mylib.map* containing:

```
SOMELIB_1.0 {
    symbol1;
    symbol2;
};
```

To link "mylib.so" I needed to pass additional argument: `-Wl,--version-script=mylib.map`